# java:40: error: exception FileNotFoundException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am trying to open a file with Java. If the operation does not work, my program should output `The file was not found, please download file with name DateTemp.csv.`. Here is my code:

```java
File myFile = new File("DateTemp.csv");                     //File Name
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);                    //scanner to input file name
try {
    //Try to display one too many array elements.
    myFile = new File("DateTemp.csv");
    for (int i = 0; i <= templow.length; i++);
    for (int i = 0; i <= temphigh.length; i++);
    //System.out.println(temphigh[i]);
    //System.out.println(templow[i]);
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Invalid array index exceeds Array Size.");                  //catch block to declare the array index was too large
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("The File was not Found, please download file with name DateTemp.csv");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do the 2nd "myFile = new File...".

Comment: And you're probably getting the error, because your path to the file **DateTemp.csv** is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);` code inside of the try block

Comment: Moving the location of the code worked, but further down the code I am getting an error with error: variable inputFile is already defined in method main(String[])
   Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);

Comment: The error should speak for itself. You already wrote `Scanner inputFile = ...` in the method and now you're trying to define it again. Either remove that line or change the second one to just `inputFile = ...` without the `Scanner` part to re-define the variable